# Viewstate has value but return System.NullReferenceException on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.6

I recently trapped by a new and very odd exception for ViewState on page postback.
I want to set a ViewState once if the page is not postback (first time loading), then use it again on the next postback if it happened.
The code is defined on page_Load as following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"])){
   if (Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out var id)){
      ViewState["mesId"] = id;
      if (!IsPostBack)
       {
          LoadData(id);
       }
       if (IsPostBack)
       {
           if (Request.Form["btnSend"] != null)
           {
               if (ViewState["mesId"] != null)
               {
                  string g = ViewState["msgId"].ToString();
                  if (Xss.GUID_Validate(g))
                  {
                       Guid mesGuid = Guid.Parse(ViewState["mesId"].ToString());
                       Send_Message(mesGuid);
                  }
               }
           }
        }
   }
}
```

After the page is loading for is not post back, everything is ok but if I call `btnSend` for do a postback, ViewState["mesId"] keep it's values and is dirty but throws null and `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

[image: error img]

I can pass through this error by using direct `Request.QueryString` but I wonder what is wrong with my code and why viewstate behavior like this?

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing `"mesId"` and `"msgId"`?

Comment: oh my god! yes you are right please let me test it

Comment: I am so tired, so make such a horrible mistake. please answer in a post I will appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be setting and checking `ViewState["mesId"]` but then crashing when loading `ViewState["msgId"]`.

Check that the keys are what you expected - this is probably just a typo.